# JqxCalendar Weekend Issue

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-plugins

I am using jqx calendar plugin.
I want to disable the weekend dates in it.
But I am unable to find any function for it in the jqx plugin files.

Any help.???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no easy way or a function to disable the weekends using jquery in jqx calendar. But you can always disable weekends dates using CSS.

Here is the code snippet to disable weekends.

```
    .jqx-calendar-cell-weekend {
    -moz-user-select: none !important;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
    border: medium none !important;
    color: #898989 !important;
    cursor: default !important;
    opacity: 0.55 !important;
    pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes it is :) No need of any Js fix for it.